# Structure Setup and intializating varibles

Tags: c

I have provided the code segment part, setting up the structure. I get 
    the error "expected an expression" when I set up the structure. Please 
    see the code segment that I have provided. I have reviewed other code 
    that should work.

```
 Can not compile the program with the program segment below. Not sure how 
 to correct it. error in the .size and .char part. This part is just the 
 code segment for the structure.


 #define MAX_SIZE 25  // max name size

 typedef struct     // structure for an employee name and height size
 {
    char name[MAX_SIZE];
    int size;
 } Employee;

 int main(int argc, char ** argv)
 {

  Employee student =        // initializes the structure
  {
    .name = { 0 },  // error expected an expression. 
    .size = MAX_SIZE    // error expected an expression.
  };                    // does not accept the .name and .size                           
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps your compiler doesn't support designated initializers. What compiler are you using?

Comment: C99 introduces designated initializers.  GCC 5 and above defaults to C11; earlier versions to C90.  You should ensure you request at least support for C99.

Comment: Your code is perfectly valid C. Microsoft does not make a compiler for the C language. They make a C++ compiler that will compile some C programs, but not those that use some C features that are not in C++, even if those features have been in the language for 20 years or more. Microsoft has stated clearly many times that they have no intention of changing this.

Answer (score 0):

I am using microsoft visual studio 2017.